Job shows as "in progress" even after pod has completed
I'm having trouble with Kubernetes Jobs not seeming to realize when they've completed. The one and only pod will have a status of "Completed", but the Job's status is still "In progress". What should I be looking at to find the disconnect here?
Job status:
status:
  ready: 0
  startTime: '2024-11-25T20:54:56Z'
  terminating: 0
  uncountedTerminatedPods:
    succeeded:
      - 69ec0a89-c6d9-4514-a3cd-ee2c80436bd7

Pod status:
status:
  conditions:
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: '2024-11-25T20:55:25Z'
      status: 'False'
      type: PodReadyToStartContainers
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: '2024-11-25T20:54:56Z'
      reason: PodCompleted
      status: 'True'
      type: Initialized
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: '2024-11-25T20:55:24Z'
      reason: PodCompleted
      status: 'False'
      type: Ready
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: '2024-11-25T20:55:24Z'
      reason: PodCompleted
      status: 'False'
      type: ContainersReady
    - lastProbeTime: null
      lastTransitionTime: '2024-11-25T20:54:56Z'
      status: 'True'
      type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
    - containerID: cri-o://5b7bda50433fc6d1951d18e6b8fbdac9538c4661bd65f772f31219a8008adca9
      image: <snip>
      imageID: <snip>
      lastState: {}
      name: add-eta-notifier-rec-runtime
      ready: false
      restartCount: 0
      started: false
      state:
        terminated:
          containerID: >-
            cri-o://5b7bda50433fc6d1951d18e6b8fbdac9538c4661bd65f772f31219a8008adca9
          exitCode: 0
          finishedAt: '2024-11-25T20:55:24Z'
          reason: Completed
          startedAt: '2024-11-25T20:54:57Z'
  hostIP: 172.17.98.168
  hostIPs:
    - ip: 172.17.98.168
  phase: Succeeded
  podIP: 10.131.1.42
  podIPs:
    - ip: 10.131.1.42
  qosClass: Guaranteed
  startTime: '2024-11-25T20:54:56Z'

